# Display 52 kinds of periodic research without a boring design

Tags: research, data, data-display

We have about 52 different kinds of researches getting released every so often, some daily, some weekly, some monthly, etc. Our current view is like

[image]

So as you can tell, it looks boring. Each link provides a file on click, and below each link there is a date. There are multiple ideas like showing a description of the latest research too which would be interesting. Also, it could be interesting to show them as a card item like this:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/

but if we have 52 of this, the page will become very convoluted...

How can we have this page look so it's the least confusing way of displaying various kinds of researches to user without getting them overwhelmed?

Comment: Rather than 'boring', what is information that is most useful to the user? is it just name and date? Is there other data that you have access to that's not displayed, such as last modified, authors, etc?

Comment: Hi Reis, and welcome to the site. We're here to discuss design questions, not to design your product. So if you have a specific question about your design, we'll help. If you ask us to do your work, we won't :-(   To get you started with your design, think about why your users will choose particular reports. Do they choose different or same ones every time? What are the properties which influence their design? Once you have this information, you can redesign your list so as to present the drivers for decisions prominently.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not doing designs.

Comment: This needs it's own UX research project - As others have already stated, you need to find out what the end users of these reports what to see and how they want to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use tiles instead of lists. A lot of space is used up for the categories, a logo could do the same (I assume the categories rarely change).

Colors could be used to indicate whether something updates weekly, monthly, or daily. Brightness could be used to indicate that something is new (maybe also a border for everything new for the user since the last login). Tiles could be dynamic in size, so the whole title and other relevant information fits in. Day, month, year, title and other info should be easy to distinguish at a glance (through font, borders, backgrounds...), so it's easier to focus on whatever someone looks for.

You could leave some space on top for a menu, where people can sort by date, title, category and so on, to create a custom view (and maybe also go back to list view). There, they could also find info on what the symbols, colors and so on mean.

Every graphical feature (color, text, border, brightness, corner...) should be easy to ignore when not needed and easy to look for when needed. So that one finds dates, titles, categories and other relevant information very fast and effortless.

If you have extra time, an alphabetical list with keywords from the titles and categories, maybe differently large for frequency, can help quickly find all articles where the title includes that keyword. You just need to exclude words no-one searches for in the context, like of, and, a, an, or, the and so on.

And you can reserve some extra large space for the newest article - or an especially important one.

If the titles are not too clear, you could have a little summary or excert appear when hovering over a tile, or at the bottom of tile (maybe as an option).

On a side note, if you have a list view, don't put more than 1 item in 1 row. rather put the date and other information besides the title. This is much easier to parse, and therefore much more practical. More boring, but faster and easier to work with.

Comment: You  are welcome ;)